json.loads key error fill with nulls, not pass
I have the following code (below). getting an error because some wind_gust records are null. When this happens I want to backfill with a null value, instead. How can I do this?
    req = requests.get(api_request_url, params=api_arguments)
    data = json.loads(req.text)

    rows = []

    for i in data["STATION"]:
        length = len(i["OBSERVATIONS"]["date_time"])
        for j in range(length):
            try: row = {
                "stationId": i["STID"],
            "wind": i["OBSERVATIONS"]["wind_gust"][j],

            except KeyError: pass


can you provide your input and expected output?

Yes. this is one record that has wind_gust. in come cases, other station id/records will be missing wind_gust: {
"STATION": [
{
"STID": "AR307"},
"OBSERVATIONS": {
"date_time": [
"2024-01-12T17:25:00Z"
],
"wind_direction_set_1": [
55.0
],
"wind_gust": [
0.444
]
        }

}

Here, you need at least j elements in your wind_gust list.
You can use the lists.get method to safely access the key and provide a default value (of j times an empty item)
Example code :
req = requests.get(api_request_url, params=api_arguments)
data = json.loads(req.text)

rows = []

for station in data["STATION"]:
    length = len(station["OBSERVATIONS"]["date_time"])
    for j in range(length):
        row = {
            "stationId": station["STID"],
            "wind": station["OBSERVATIONS"].get("wind_gust", [None] * length)[j],
        }
        rows.append(row)

